# Checking whether a user is logged in using stormpath and spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, stormpath

I have a simple web application which I am writing using spring-boot and storm path for user authentication. (I'm actually using spring-boot-starter-stormpath-thymeleaf)

I have a have the following request mapping in my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/secure", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String secure(Model mode, HttpServletRequest request) {
    Account account = AccountResolver.INSTANCE.getAccount(request);

    if (account != null)
        return "secure";
    else
        return "redirect:/login?next=secure";
}
```

which forces a user to login to view the secure page. It works, but it doesn't feel like it is the most elegant of solutions. Is there a better way? I think a solution with filters should be possible but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Just curious - are you using a security framework like Apache Shiro or Spring Security?  This answer will determine the best recommendation for your particular use case.

Comment: I was looking at spring security

Answer (score 3):

The current Stormpath Spring Boot starter does not (yet) have an authentication filter, but it will on future releases for those that want an out-of-the-box experience without having to use Spring Security or Apache Shiro.

That said, we're currently working on natively supporting Spring Security and Apache Shiro as Spring Boot starters that 'just work' with the Stormpath Spring Boot starter.  Until we can release those, creating a custom servlet filter as you indicate is the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

Are you also using the Stormpath Servlet as well?

If so, you could do what you need following [this piece of documentation](https://docs.stormpath.com/java/servlet-plugin/access-control.html). This way you will only need to declare which are the resources of your application that you want to secure and Stormpath's authc filter will prompt for authentication when required.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Spring MVC, you should use Spring Security and have Stormpath acting as an authentication provider. Then use the standard Spring Security tools to declare access rules and inject the current user where needed.